# How to identify transmit labels for a particular equipment in ARINC429?

Tags: arinc-429

As i can see, each equipment has a set of labels which the equipment may supposed to be received. Say if i am Equipment 03Ch (Tire pressure monitoring system), i will be configured to receive below labels

LABEL 060 -> Tire pressure (Left Outer)

LABEL 061 -> Tire pressure (Left Inner)

LABEL 062 -> Tire pressure (Right Inner)

LABEL 063 -> Tire pressure (Right Outer)

LABEL 064 -> Tire pressure (Nose)

But how may i know, what are the labels should i send ?

Comment: The Equip ID identifies the source of the data labels, not the consumer. Equip 03Ch will output your list, not receive them. The TPMS measures the tire pressures and sends the data to the onboard maintenance and cockpit display systems.

Comment: Looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, perhaps you could report that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

As Gerry mentioned in their comment, the equipment ID label (377) indicates to the receiver how to decode the labels being received on that ARINC 429 channel.

The transmitting equipment (Tire Pressure Monitoring System) would send label 377 with the value 03C at it's appropriate rate (usually every 1000 ms) and then labels 060 through 064 at their appropriate rate.

The receiving equipment gets the Equipment ID from label 377 it received and then knows to decode labels 060-064 according to the TPMS definitions.

Comment: So can i say, 060-064 are the labels transmitted by equipment 03C (Of course label decoding depends on equipment ID). My actual question is Let say i am Equipment 03C, what else are the labels should i transmit (or) i always act as a receiver ? Should i get a table that differentiates transmit and receive labels for particular equipment ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: ARINC 429 is unidirectional, so unless you have a separate ARINC 429 Rx channel, your 03C equipment will only be a transmitter. I didn't see any other labels for 03C in the spec, so any additional labels you transmit will be product defined (you define them)